# Find duplicate values in javascript associative array (hash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

Have an key value pair like below

```
var point = [];
point["I1"] = 1000;
point["I2"] = 2000;
point["I3"] = 1000;
point["I4"] = 5000;
point["I5"] = 2000;
point["I6"] = 4000;
```

want to find the duplicate values, result hash should contain ONLY DUPLICATE value information.

```
result["1000"] = " I1,I3";
result["2000"] = "I2,I5";
```

duplicate values should be keys of result hash.

I sort the array, but clueless to traverse hash to check the duplicate values to build the result hash

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jbs9y896/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check all values with loop over keys of point.
I changed your terms a little bit. You can set extra keys for `Array` but you'd better use an `Object` instead.
The result for each value would be an array which can be converted to comma separated values with just a `toString` call on each array.

#### Edit

As request is edited, to contain `only duplicates` You can just loop again (but this time over the `hash`) and get which has more than one result.

```js
var point = {
  I1: 1000,
  I2: 2000,
  I3: 1000,
  I4: 5000,
  I5: 2000,
  I6: 4000,
};

var hash = Object.create(null);
var result = Object.create(null);

Object.keys(point).forEach(k => {
  var grp = point[k];
  (grp in hash) ? hash[grp].push(k): (hash[grp] = [k]);
});

for (key in hash)
  if (hash[key].length > 1)
    result[key] = hash[key].toString();

console.log(hash['1000'].toString());
console.log(hash);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Like to have only the duplicate values . The duplicate values in Point[] are 1000 and 2000. want to have only duplicate data in hash[]

Comment: @SKay It is simple to find out how to get what you want out of `hash`. BTW I've added `result`.

Comment: Got it, i want to understand this line  (grp in hash) ? hash[grp].push(k): (hash[grp] = [k]);   mainly the else part.

Comment: @SKay This is kind of `if statement` syntax. if there is a key in hash with value of `grp` then push new value into `hash[grp]` else set `hash[grp]` to an array with value of `k`.

Comment: @mortesaT thanks . [k] means value added to array. new to me! will appreciate if there is any links to know on javascript on hash and more. thanks.

Comment: @SKay `[k]` means create an array with initial value of `k`. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

to get `result["1000"] = "I1,I3"` instead of `result["1000"] = ['I1','I3']`:

```
var point = {};
point["I1"] = 1000;
point["I2"] = 2000;
point["I3"] = 1000;
point["I4"] = 5000;
point["I5"] = 2000;
point["I6"] = 4000;

var hash = Object.create(null);
Object.keys(point).forEach(k => {
  var grp = point[k];    
  (grp in hash) ? hash[grp] = hash[grp] += ',' + k: (hash[grp] = k);
})

console.log(hash);
```